# telegrambot Обрабатываем нажатие на inlineKeyboard

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Нужно написать бота, который вначале выдает клавиатуру с определенными кнопками, а в зависимости от выбора пользователя выдает другую клавиатуру и т.д.

```
public static class Program
{
    private static TelegramBotClient Bot;

    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Bot = new TelegramBotClient("<api>");

        var me = await Bot.GetMeAsync();
        Console.Title = me.Username;

        Bot.OnMessage += BotOnMessageReceived;
        Bot.OnMessageEdited += BotOnMessageReceived;
        Bot.OnCallbackQuery += BotOnCallbackQueryReceived;
        Bot.StartReceiving(Array.Empty<UpdateType>());
        Console.WriteLine($"Start listening for @{me.Username}");

        Console.ReadLine();
        Bot.StopReceiving();
    }

    private static async void BotOnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs messageEventArgs)
    {
        var message = messageEventArgs.Message;
        if (message == null || message.Type != MessageType.Text) return;

        switch (message.Text.Split(' ').First())
        {
            case "/inline1":
                await Bot.SendChatActionAsync(message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.Typing);

                var inlineKeyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
                {
                    // first row
                    new []
                    {
                        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("1.1", "11"),
                        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("1.2", "12"),
                    },
                    // second row
                    new []
                    {
                        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("2.1", "21"),
                        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("2.2", "22"),
                    }
                });
                await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chatId: message.Chat.Id,
                    text: "Choose",
                    replyMarkup: inlineKeyboard
                );
                break;
            case "11":
                await Bot.SendChatActionAsync(message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.Typing);

                inlineKeyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
                {
                    // first row
                    new []
                    {
                        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("1.1", "11"),
                        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("1.2", "12"),
                    },
                    // second row
                    new []
                    {
                        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("2.1", "21"),
                        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("2.2", "22"),
                    }
                });
                await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chatId: message.Chat.Id,
                    text: "Choose",
                    replyMarkup: inlineKeyboard
                );
                break;
            default:
                const string usage = "Don't know";
                await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chatId: message.Chat.Id,
                    text: usage,
                    replyMarkup: new ReplyKeyboardRemove()
                );
                break;
        }
    }

    private static async void BotOnCallbackQueryReceived(object sender, CallbackQueryEventArgs callbackQueryEventArgs)
    {
        var callbackQuery = callbackQueryEventArgs.CallbackQuery;

        await Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(
            callbackQueryId: callbackQuery.Id,
            text: "11"
        );

        await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(
            chatId: callbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id,
            text: "11"
        );
    }
}
```

}
И тут проблема если пользователь самостоятельно пишет вариант мы ему клавиатуру предоставим, а если он выбирает кнопку то ничего не происходит.

Здесь проблема в событиях т.к. событие ввода данных пользователем

`void BotOnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs messageEventArgs)`

а событие получения:

```
void BotOnCallbackQueryReceived(object sender, CallbackQueryEventArgs callbackQueryEventArgs)
```

Аргументы у них разные и при попытки подписаться на них выдает ошибку на группу методов. Как их совместить вместе не пойму.

Comment: Отладчиком глядели что происходит? Ну и у вас вторая клавиатура в точности такая же, как и первая.

Comment: @tym32167 сама программа работает без ошибок. Просто я не пойму почему не вызывается  событие при нажатии встроенной клавиатуры. Может она как то по другому вызывается. Но тогда как?

Answer (score 0):

А почему ты делаешь через InlineKeyboardMarkup, тебе нужно отдавать кнопки, так что используй класс ReplyKeyboardMarkup. В него добавляешь кнопки KeyboardButton, а потом отсылаешь BotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "Hello", replyMarkup: keyboard);

UPD. Пример кода

```
        var keyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
        var key1 = new KeyboardButton("key1");
        var key2= new KeyboardButton("key2");
        var key3= new KeyboardButton("key3");

        var list = new List<List<KeyboardButton>>();
        var keyboardList = new List<KeyboardButton>();
        keyboardList.Add(key1);
        keyboardList.Add(key2);
        keyboardList.Add(key3);

        list.Add(keyboardList);
        keyboard.Keyboard = list;

        BotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "Hello", replyMarkup: keyboard);
```

Comment: Приведи пример кода пожалуйста

Comment: @polsok, обновил, можешь смотреть

Comment: не пойму что вы предлагаете. Ну заменю я InlineKeyboard на ReplyKeyboardMarkup. Как мне при нажатии на кнопки открывать новую клавиатуру? Причем что бы c новой клавиатуры я мог вернуться назад назад?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы выбрать меню в `bot.send_message` необходимо его прописать после `reply_markup`. В данном примере у меня несколько таких меню-кнопок. И для поддержания диалога я использую коллбеки

```
otherMenu = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True,False)
otherMenu.row('Тест')    

cancel_menu = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
cancel_menu.row('Отмена⛔')    

nomenclaturaMenu = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True,False)
nomenclaturaMenu.row('Прикрепить фото️','Сделать фото‍')

if message.text=='Прикрепить фото️': #'Прикрепить фото':
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите файлы.  Как завершите - нажмите Далее⏭', reply_markup = ok_cancel_menu)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, photo_bind_photo_step)

def photo_bind_photo_step(message):
    user = user_dict[message.chat.id]
    if (message.text=="Отмена⛔"):
        cancelation(message)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите пункт меню', reply_markup=otherMenu ) # вот тут отобразится otherMenu 
        return
```

Comment: странный какой то код это точно c#? И можно поподробнее расписать что за telebot? может надо библиотеку какую подключить? Telegram.Bot не понимает таких переменных.